# Read this Excel sheet OR that sheet in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is an Excel workbook file, and there can be a sheet called "Purple" or "Blue", but there would never be a case where it has sheets with both names.  There are a number of unrelated excel sheets in this file. How would you change the `sheet_name =`  condition below to account for this?

```
import pandas as pd

tempTable = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(r, 'random_file.xlsx'), 
                                       sheet_name='Blue', 
                                       header=10, 
                                       nrows=10)
```

Comment: Is this the only sheet that you have in excel file?

Comment: No there are a lot of other sheets in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant solution but should work

```
def read_sheet(sheet_name):
    return pd.read_excel(os.path.join(r, 'random_file.xlsx'), 
                         sheet_name=sheet_name, 
                         header=10, 
                         nrows=10)
tempTable = None
try:
    tempTable = read_sheet('Blue')
except ValueError:
    tempTable = read_sheet('Purple')
```